# каким образом реализовать блоки

Tags: javascript

На данный момент у меня есть RADIO с 3 вариантами выбора, и в зависимости от того что выбрать будет показан блок, эти 3 блоки одинаковые, но у них разные заголовки и параграфы, так вот, мне показалось нецелесообразно писать 3 одинаковых блока, и я подумал, реализовать один блок, но входные данные определял js, мой вопрос заключается в том, как это сделать по современным стандартам. Я думал сделать объект с 3 объектов в котором будут хранится заголовки и параграфы, и да я не прошу за меня написать код лишь метод реализации, и да извините, если вопрос глупый, я еще только учусь работать с js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как удобнее, так и сделайте.
Я бы, например, реализовал следующим образом.

```js
let obj = { // данные храним в массиве
  id0: {name: 'Иван Иванов', age: 18, from: 'Russia, Moscow'},
  id1: {name: 'Пётр Петров', age: 43, from: 'Ukraina, Kiev'},
  id3: {name: 'Сергей Сидоров', age: 20, from: 'Belarus, Minsk'}
  }, 
  list = document.querySelector('#list'),
  content = document.querySelector('#content'),
  temp = `<h1>%name%</h1>
    <p>Age: <b>%age%</b></p>
    <p>From: <b>%from%</b></p>`; // "шаблон" под данные храним отдельно

for(let key in obj)
  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<input type="radio" id="${key}" name="obj"><label for="${key}">${obj[key].name}</label>`); // Выводим все вариант как переключатель

list.addEventListener('click', e => { // Вешаем обработчик
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    let data = obj[e.target.id];
    content.innerHTML = temp // Меняем вывод данные под "заготовленный" шаблон.
      .replace(/%name%/gm, data.name)
      .replace(/%age%/gm, data.age)
      .replace(/%from%/gm, data.from);
  }
});

list.querySelector('input').click();
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ, я примерно так и думал сделать